# Debugging StoreKit functionality without a device

Tags: ipad, storekit

I'm porting an app with in-app purchase functionality from the iPhone to the iPad, but the simulator doesn't handle any StoreKit calls (they fail immediately with a warning). Since there are no iPads available yet, I can't use a device for debugging.

I have thought of a few alternatives:

- Use the iPhone code as is. This is the safe bet since everything already works on the iPhone, but it will not feel right on the iPad (there are several ViewControllers in a NavigationController involved on the iPhone, but everything could fit on one screen on the pad).
- Write a test framework for StoreKit. I actually started doing this, but I won't be able to finish it in time.
- Submit untested code and pray. Nah, just kidding -- that's not an option :)

So, any thoughts? Has anyone else written a test framework for this kind of thing? I googled a bit but couldn't find anything. I'm grateful for any thoughts on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I ended up using the same classes on both iPhone and iPad, with different .xib files to make it look slightly better. It's not perfect, but it will do until I get my own iPad. There was still more coding involved than I would have liked, considering that I couldn't test it fully on the simulator, but I did at least get to test most of it on the iPhone.

Comment: ...and of course there was a connection that I had missed in IB, causing Apple to reject the app. I then disabled the whole in-app purchase functionality and got the app approved that way. When I managed to get hold of a real iPad, I found and fixed the problem in minutes. This morning, the fixed version was approved, so case closed for me :).